# jQuery filters out inline AJAX request when page AJAX'd in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a history API script that loads in content from the URL into the pages main div and then changes the URL accordingly. However for reasons that I shall not explain for brevity, I am having to use an inline script in a page to load in an audio player. When the page with the player is AJAX'd in with the history API the inline script is removed.

I have had problems with jQuery's AJAX function filtering out inline scripts before but got round it with this in the history API script:

```
var dom = $(responseData);
dom.filter('script').each(function(){//function to allow inline javascript
    $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
});
```

That is not working in the case of this inline script:

```
//append player with js so doesn't show when js disabled
$('#profile_content').append('<div class="artistFeedItem" data-type="track" data-id ="<?php echo $E_ID; ?>" data-ts ="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><img src="../files/images/bigLoader.gif" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></div>'); //loading

$('*[data-type="track"].artistFeedItem').each(function () {
    //Get player for track and send off variables
    var E_ID = "<?php echo $E_ID; ?>";
    var T_ID = "<?php echo $T_ID; ?>";
    var T_url = "<?php echo $T_url; ?>";
    var T_name = "<?php echo $T_name; ?>";
    var T_timestamp = "<?php echo $T_timestamp; ?>";
    var T_pic = "<?php echo $T_pic; ?>";
    var A_name = "<?php echo $name; ?>";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'player/body_player_template',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            T_url: T_url,
            T_name: T_name
        },
        success: function (responseData) {
            $('*[data-type="track"]*[data-id="' + E_ID + '"].artistFeedItem').html(responseData);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('*[data-type="track"]*[data-id="' + E_ID + '"].artistFeedItem').html("Sorry, this track couldn't be loaded. Try refreshing the page.");
        }
    });
});
```

That's the inline script that is being filtered out when AJAX'd in.

I hope that you understand what i'm asking and I hope there is a way to prevent this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why I didn't spot this for so long but the scripts were being executed before DOM was loaded. I have changed the functions around so scripts are executed after the new DOM is loaded in.